# Is in Java the same possibility to print with "{}" like in C#

Tags: java

I couldn't find in Google.

**Is in Java the same possibility to print with "{}" like in  C# ?**

**C#:**

```
  namespace Start
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string a = "Hi";

            Console.WriteLine("{0}", a);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Java: ???**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yep, the syntax is inherited from C:

```
String a = "Hi!";
System.out.printf("%s\n", a);
```

The thing to be mindful of is that there are different kinds of formatting specifiers. The example uses `%s`, for formatting strings. If you're printing an integer or long, you use `%d`. There are also options for controlling things like min/max length, padding and decimal places. For the full list of options, check [the JavaDoc of `java.util.Formatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

Answer (score 2):

[`MessageFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) is what you are looking for:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String a = "Hi";
    MessageFormat mFormat = new MessageFormat("{0}");
    String[] params = {a};
    System.out.println(mFormat.format(params));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best equivalence is java.util.Formatter.

For instance:

```
Formatter formatter = new Formatter().format("%s %d", "myString", 1);
System.out.println(formatter.toString());
```

Output:

```
myString 1
```

See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use also

```
System.out.format(.....);
```